# Is it possible to perform push and pop operations on a Javascript hashmap?

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I have a Javascript hashmap like so :

```
var hash = new Object();
hash["1000001"] = {value="red"};
hash["1000002"] = {value="green"};
hash["1000003"] = {value="blue"};
```

I know that `hash.pop()` will not work. However, is there a way to find out which element was added last into the hash, so that i can delete it?

Maybe i should have framed my question like this : "*Is there a way to find out the order in which the elements have been added into a hash? (without adding a timestamp field for every element that is added into the hash)*"

Comment: Object.keys(hash).pop() usually works. if you store the object the keys can get re-ordered, so look out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You'll have to keep track of this yourself. Something like:

```
function setOrdered(hash, key, val) {
    if (!(key in hash)) {
        hash.order = hash.order || [];
        hash.order.push(key);
    }
    hash[key] = val;
}
function popOrdered(hash) {
    if (!hash.order || hash.order.length === 0) { 
        throw new Error("Empty hash");
    }
    var lastKey = hash.order.pop();
    var result = hash[lastKey];
    delete hash[lastKey];
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
> var hash = {};
> setOrdered(hash, 'a', 10);
> setOrdered(hash, 'b', 20);
> setOrdered(hash, 'c', 30);
> popOrdered(hash);
30    
> hash
{'a': 10, 'b': 20}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just store an array that keeps track of the indexes, since it will keep it ordered, and then give the item a push and pop function:

```
var hash = new Object();
hash.indexes=[];
hash.push = function(index, item) {
  hash[index] = item;
  hash.indexes.push(index);
}
hash.pop = function() {
 item = hash.indexes.pop();
 ret_item = hash[item];
 delete hash[item];
 return ret_item;
}
hash.push("1000001", {value:"red"});
hash.push("1000002", {value:"green"});
hash.push("1000003", {value:"blue"});
hash.pop()
//{value: "blue"}
```